# Удаление слов которые начинаются на гласную букву

Tags: c++, строки

Я пытался сделать удаление которые начинаются на гласную букву , но мой код не удаляет вообще . В чем может быть проблема? Прошу прошения, если вопрос выглядит плохо оформленным.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void DeleteVowels(char words[]);

int main()
{
    char words[255];
    
    cout << "Enter words separated by space:";
    gets_s(words);

    DeleteVowels(words);

    cout << "Line view after deleting words:";
    puts(words);

    return 0;
}

void DeleteVowels(char words[])
{
    char vowels[13] = "AaEeIiOoUuYy";
    int counter = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    int startwords, endwords;

    for (i = 0; words[i]; i++)
    {
        if (words[i] == ' ' || words[i] == '\0')
        {
            while (words[i] == ' ') i++;
            startwords = i;
            while (words[i] != ' ' && words[i] != '\0') i++;
            while (words[i] == ' ') i++;
            endwords = i;
            for (j = 0; vowels[j]; j++)
            {
                if (startwords == vowels[j])
                {
                    strcpy(&words[startwords], &words[endwords]);
                }
            }
            i -= endwords - startwords + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример работающего кода:

```
void DeleteVowels(char words[])
{
    char vowels[13] = "AaEeIiOoUuYy";
    int counter = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    int startwords, endwords;
    int len = strlen(words);

    for (i = 0; words[i];)
    {
        while (words[i] == ' ') i++;
        startwords = i;
        while (words[i] != ' ' && words[i] != '\0') i++;
        while (words[i] == ' ') i++;
        endwords = i;
        for (j = 0; vowels[j]; j++)
        {
            //Сравниваем первую букву слова с буквой из массива, а не индекс этой буквы
            if (words[startwords] == vowels[j])
            {
                //Копируем всю строку за найденым словом вперед, тем самым затираем найденное слово
                memmove(&words[startwords], &words[endwords], len - endwords + 1);
                //Корректируем индекс т.к. теперь длина строки изменилась
                i -= endwords - startwords;
                //Корректируем длину строки (по подсказке AlexGlebe)
                len -= endwords - startwords;
                //Нет смысла продолжать циклу пробегать по массиву букв
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Для примера я вводил строчку: `Abc defgh ijklmn O pqRsTu vWx Yz`

И получал такую: `defgh pqRsTu vWx`

Comment: А как сделать чтобы удаляло слова которые заканчивается на гласную букву?

Comment: новую переменную рядом с `startwords, endwords` создай и после строчки `while (words[i] != ' ' && words[i] != '\0') i++;` инициализируешь созданную переменную `i - 1`. А дальше при проверке `words[startwords]` меняешь `startwords` на созданную переменную.

Comment: Cпасибо , понял.

Comment: После удаления каждого слова нужно обновлять длину строки `len`. Получается у вас лишняя работа.

Comment: @AlexGlebe для строки размером 255 байт это не критично, но спасибо за подсказку. Дополнил код.

Answer (score 1):

Ну не удаляет, потому-что вы сравниваете индекс с буквами

```
if (startwords == vowels[j])
```

скорее всего надо так :

```
if ( words[startwords] == vowels[j])
```

Копирование букв друг на друга приведёт к неопределённости.

```
strcpy(&words[startwords], &words[endwords]);
```

Делать нужно функцией `memmove` :

```
memmove(&words[startwords] , &words[endwords] , strlen(&words[endwords])+1);
```